# form submitting twice via ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

Inserting into `mysql` using `php` file called via `AJAX`. Before `insert` statement php code performs `select` query to *find duplicate records* and continue to `insert statement`.

> **Issue**: When calling php file from ajax. it executed twice and getting response as duplicate record.

well i tried `error_log` from insert function its called twice.

*Trigger point of form validation*

```
$("#load-modal").on("click","#addcountryformsubmitbtn",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $("#addcountryform"), $url = $form.attr('action');  
    $form.submit();
});
```

*This is how form submitted after validation:*

```
}).on('success.form.bv', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $("#addcountryform"), $url = $form.attr('action'); 
    $.post($url,$form.serialize()).done(function(dte){ $("#load-modal").html(dte); });
});
```

**using bootstrapvalidator, Core PHP, mysqli, Chrome Browser.**

*Actual JS:*

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $php_self_country="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pg=countrycontent"; ?>";
            $("#country-content").load($php_self_country,loadfunctions);
            $("#country-content").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#country-loading-div").show();
                var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
                $("#country-content").load($php_self_country,{"page":page}, function(){
                    $("#country-loading-div").hide();
                    loadfunctions();
                });             
            });
            $("#country-content").on("click","#closebtn",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#country-content").load($php_self_country,loadfunctions);
            });
        });
        function loadfunctions(){
            $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); 
            $("#country-content").on("click","#addcountrybtn, #addcountrylargebtn",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $php_self_country,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'addcountry':'Y' },
                    dataType: "html",
                    cache: false
                }).done(function(msg){
                    $("#load-modal").html(msg);
                    $("#load-modal").modal('show');
                    $('input[type="radio"]').iCheck({ checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal', radioClass: 'iradio_minimal' });
                    modalvalidation();
                }).fail(function() {
                    $("#load-modal").html( "Request Failed. Please Try Again Later." );
                });         
            });
            $("#country-content").on("click",".tools a",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var recordid = $(this).attr("record-id");
                $.ajax({
                    url: $php_self_country,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'modifycountry':recordid },
                    dataType: "html",
                    cache: false
                }).done(function(msg){
                    $("#load-modal").html(msg);
                    $("#load-modal").modal('show');
                    $('input[type="radio"]').iCheck({ checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal', radioClass: 'iradio_minimal' });
                    modalvalidation();
                }).fail(function() {
                    $("#load-modal").html( "Request Failed. Please Try Again Later." );
                });
            });
            $("#load-modal").on("click","#addcountryformsubmitbtn",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $form = $("#addcountryform"), $url = $form.attr('action');  
                $form.submit();
            });
            $("#load-modal").on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
                window.location.href=$php_self_country_pg;
            });
        }
        function modalvalidation(){ 
            $('#addcountryform').bootstrapValidator({
                message: 'This value is not valid',
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    [-------Validation part comes here----------]
                }
            }).on('success.form.bv', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var $form = $("#addcountryform"), $url = $form.attr('action'); 
                $.post($url,$form.serialize()).done(function(dte){ $("#load-modal").html(dte); });
            });
        }
```

*HTML*

this html is called on button click `addcountrybtn` via `AJAX` and write in to div `load-modal` which is in base html file.

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> <?php echo COUNTRYLABEL; ?></h4>
    </div>      
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" method="POST" action="self.php" name="addcountryform" id="addcountryform" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label for="countryname" class="pull-right">Country Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="lnbrd">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="countryname" placeholder="Enter Country Name">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label for="crncyname" class="pull-right">Currency Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="lnbrd">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="crncyname" placeholder="Enter Currency Name">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label for="crncycode" class="pull-right">Currency Code</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="lnbrd">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="crncycode" placeholder="Enter Currency Code">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label for="forrate" class="pull-right">Foreign Currency Rate<?php echo isset($icon)?$icon:''; ?></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="lnbrd">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="forrate" placeholder="Enter Foreign Currency Rate.">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label for="taxpercent" class="pull-right">Tax &#37;</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="lnbrd">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="taxpercent" placeholder="Enter Tax Percentage">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>         
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="addcountryformsubmitbtn">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note:- in Database point of view code works as expected.

Comment: Can you show the HTML of `#addcountryformsubmitbtn`? Please check that it has the `type="button"` attribute.

Comment: @sp00m find HTML in question. _tried both_ `type="button"` and `type="submit"` output still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things that I have seen could possibly be the cause.

If you are using IE, I have seen that perform a GET immediately before doing a POST (to the same URL, with the same data being sent over), so it could be worth trying to check for that on your server (and ignore the GET)

Something else it maybe to add the following to the end of your button click events after the AJAX call (actually, normally I'd put the first line at the top with the prevent default, and the return statement obviously goes very last)...

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
return false;
```

Comment: its working!!! just added `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` next to all `e.preventDefault();` and didn't use `return false;`; will it cause issue in future?? tested in IE10 and Chrome :)